# using local audio driver for external jainsip stack on android

Tags: android, voip, jain-sip

Hello i have successfully inplemented the jainsip stack on the android and was wondering if i could use the local audio library  instead of an external.so lib.  a modified version of Jainsip is included in android 2.3+. My driver seems to decode audio sporadically from time to time and would like to use a more stable lib..  Any ideas?